# Learning Subversion

Tags: svn, version-control

I am new to Version Control System and i started with Subversion (svn).

I know and used few basics stuff about SVN and i also used with Eclipse using Subversive.

Now i want to take this further to learning whole VCS with Subversion, so i came across 2 books

- [Official Online Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)
- [Pragmatic Version Control using Subversion](http://pragprog.com/book/svn2/pragmatic-version-control-using-subversion)

So which one i should go with ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering how much is out of date or changed from the *Pragmatic Version Control using Subversion (2nd edition)* coverage of Subversion **1.3** (when the current version is 1.7 and has some significant changes over the years)

The *svnbook* I found to be well written and had some nice examples, and would suggest it instead of paying for something so far out of date.

Comment: i had look at the Pragmatic book index , 
it looks concise and chapters also looks good for get started , on other hand, svn book is massive.
lets see going to start with Pragmatic and then will refer to Online book

Answer (score 2):

Some companies offer free training webinars as well as SVNref cards which are like cheat sheets for different topics:

http://www.wandisco.com/training-content

http://www.wandisco.com/svnref

Forums dedicated to Subversion are great resources as well:

http://www.svnforum.org/forum.php

Answer (score 0):

Another tutorial that might help you more is the [Tortoise docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/support.html), if you're on Windows you might find them a more accessible way to get into SVN, very well written and lots of screenshots.